# Как сделать события в текстовой игре в разноброс?

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

я делаю текстовую игру на c# уже сделал 3 события и хочу узнать как сделать , чтобы эти события попадались в рандомном порядке

Comment: используйте класс Random

Comment: 1. добавить события в массив; 2. `var randomEvent = array[Random.Shared.Next(array.Length)]`

Comment: Можете подсказать как добавить евент в массив?(я просто новичёк)

Comment: Как вы сделали "события"? А то мне кажется мы их по разному понимаем.

Comment: В Console.WriteLine написал текст ивента потом создал переменную "a" далее Consol.WriteLine(1.первый вариант ответа);Console.WriteLine(2.второй вариант  ответа); дальше a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine) if a == 1 дальше через Console.WriteLine(действие которое будет если нажать на "1") if a == 2 Console.WriteLine(действие которое будет если нажать на "2")

Comment: Ну да, мы с вами по-разному понимаем "события". Для меня события, это `event` в языке C#, а не некий текстовый "вариант". Вам уже сказали как сделать выше, тут обычная работа с массивами, прочитайте про них. Условно будет `var events = new []{  "Пойти в огород", "Покушать", "Посетить магазин", "Спать" }`, ну а дальше, как сказали выше `var event = events[Random.Shared.Next(events.Length)];`, на выходе будет 1 случайный текст. Текст естественно меняйте на что угодно, роли не играет, ибо это простые массивы и индексы.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ , то есть мне нужно будет каждое событие вписать в var events ?

Comment: Могу ли я просто дать номер каждому событю и потом вставить эти номера в массив ?

Comment: Программирование - это творчество, где каждый человек создает свой шедевр) Так что, пробуйте, пытайтесь, изучайте, старайтесь, творите в конце концов. А вот когда уже не получится, приходите за советом, поможем.

Comment: Хорошо , спасибо , пойду лучше изучу класс рандом

Comment: @hamster-32 лучше начните изучать сначала основы C#, а не лезьте сразу в юнити, ничем хорошим это не закончится, скорее всего, юнити никуда от вас не убежит, а вот основы знать нужно